# Dynamic Rate Limiting for REST API which uses Auto Scaling & Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, autoscaling, rate-limiting, amazon-elb

I have an **REST API** running in **AWS EC2** instance and I'm having **Nginx** server inside the EC2 to handle the rate limiting (**QPS**) for the clients. My plan is to build an **Auto Scaling** with **Load Balancer** architecture with this API.

I've configured everything to setup the **Load Balancer** and the **Auto Scaling** in the AWS and the Auto Scaling works based on my **Dynamic Scaling Policy**.

**Query :** The Auto Scaling broke the rate limiting done by Nginx, Since Nginx is residing inside the EC2 server and now I have **N number of EC2's for the API** the QPS given to clients is also **increased N times**.

> For Example if ii have set **25 QPS** in Nginx for a **client named
> X** & in this Auto Scaling architecture say for an instance there is
> **4 servers** running and the clients request goes to various servers (we are not sure that all request goes to same server in a second) and
> the QPS of the client increases to **25*4=100 QPS**.

What is the solution for this kind of problem?

1. Do I need to Have a **separate server for Nginx** and do rate limiting
   in it and then send the requests to the Auto Scaling?
2. Is there any **dynamic way to update the nginx config** in every EC2 based on the number of instances spun out by Auto Scaling Group?
3. **Any other AWS service** to deal with this kind of problem?

I heard about something like **CloudFront Distribution -> AWS WAF -> ALB** etc. but not getting how that architecture to be used.

Any other solution also welcomed......!!!

Answer (score 0):

The AWS solution for implementing rate limiting on an API is to use [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) in front of your load balancer, and then enable [usage plans with rate limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html) on the API Gateway.

Comment: With AWS API Gateway should I use the lamba to achieve this? or I can connect the Load balancer directly?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-application-load-balancers/